# Facebook Graph API: How can I search a specific user's statuses for a certain keyword?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to be able to search/filter a user's statuses for a certain keyword. I thought I could do something like this:

```
graph.facebook.com/_user_id_/statuses?q=term
```

Or even:

```
graph.facebook.com/_user_id_/search?q=term&type=status
```

But none of those work and I can't find any documentation on this. I know I can do it with FQL, but the statuses method of the Graph API would give me *likes* and *comments* to each status as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with FQL, it just takes a multiquery to get it done:

```
{
'posts_w_keyword': 'SELECT post_id, actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me()
                     AND strpos(message, "keyword") > -1',
'post_comments':   'SELECT post_id, from_id, text FROM comment WHERE post_id IN
                     (SELECT post_id FROM #posts_w_keyword)',
'post_likes':      'SELECT post_id, user_id FROM like WHERE post_id IN
                     (SELECT post_id FROM #posts_w_keyword)'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I ended up doing, but it gives me three different sets of data (posts, comments, and likes) as opposed to one set with the comments and likes associated with the post. Not a huge deal, just kind of annoying.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the Graph API is limited with what it can filter, so you've got to get the different rows with FQL and them piece them together in your script.